# SDL2_image not initializing

Tags: c++, sdl-2, sdl-image

Im trying to load a .png file with SDL2 and SDL2_image. SDL2 initializes properly while SDL2_image just fails for no apparent reason, please help.

IMG_Init() returns 0

IMG_GetError() returns nothing

I'm using SDL2 2.0.10 and SDL2_image 2.0.5 (latest versions afaik)
I do have all needed dll files in the same folder as my executable (SDL2.dll, SDL2_image.dll, libpng16-16.dll, zlib1.dll as I'm only using png files right now)

I have no idea why this isn't working and I have been trying to find an answer for at least 2 hours now

My code:

```
if(IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG) != 0) {

        std::cout << "Failed to init sdl_image"<<IMG_GetError()<<std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `!= 0` should be `!= IMG_INIT_PNG`.

Comment: I just checked and it works! I feel so dumb for making such a pointless thread.

Answer (score 2):

As HolyBlackCat pointed out, it should be `IMG_INIT(IMG_INIT_PNG) != IMG_INIT_PNG` instead of `IMG_INIT(IMG_INIT_PNG) != 0`